# SQL SELECT по таблице с внешними ключами других таблиц

Tags: sql

проблема заключается в следующем..

Есть 3 таблицы:

**Таблица Клиенты:** поля Клиент.Id, Фамилия

**Таблица Услуги:** поля Услуга.Id, Название_Услуги

Третья таблица является связывающей вышеописанных таблиц:

**Клиент_Услуга:** entry.Id, Клиент, Услуга, где Клиент - внешний ключ таблицы "Клиенты" и Услуга - внешний ключ таблицы "Услуги". Записи в нее добавляются, когда клиент выбрал ту или иную услугу.

Мне необходимо сделать запрос, в котором при выборе конкретной услуги будут отображаться все фамилии клиентов, выбравших данную услугу.

Помогите пожалуйста разобраться, как правильно сформулировать данный запрос

Answer (score 1):

Если правильно понял суть вопроса и архитектуру, то данный запрос должен отработать.

```
SELECT Фамилия from клиент
INNER JOIN клиент_услуга ON клиент.Id = клиент_услуга.Клиент
WHERE клиент_услуга.Услуга = КАКОЙ-ТО-ВАШ-ID
```

Comment: А зачем тут `LEFT JOIN`?

Comment: @ГерманБорисов можно просто inner join, а что не так?

Comment: Не так то, что мы сначала явно говорим, что нам нужно породить записи с `клиент_услуга.Услуга` равным `NULL` для клиентов, у которых нет услуг, а затем их убираем. Многие СУБД проведут оптимизацию с заменой на `INNER JOIN`, но не все.

Comment: @ГерманБорисов тогда да, пишем просто join или inner join